# Django- How do I add hidden fields to a formset and populate them?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a project that has a RSVP form on it. Right now I have it functioning to process their basic info including number of additional guests they are bringing with them. This number is then used to populate X number of fields in a formset on the next page that just asks for guest names and comments.

what I'm looking to be able to do is add a hidden field to the formset of guest names which would contain the name of the person who registered them as coming.

I am already passing session data to prepopulate the first guest name with the registering guest's info, and I have a session variable defined that could populate the hidden field. I just need to know how to add the field to the formset.

from django.db import models

```
#models.py
class Guest(models.Model):
    ATTENDING_CHOICES = (
        (u'Yes', u'Yes'),
        (u'No', u'No'),
        (u'Maybe', u'Maybe?')
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    attending = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ATTENDING_CHOICES)
    no_of_guests = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total # of guests', max_length=3)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s - %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name, self.email)

class GuestsAttending(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comments = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    #This is the field that I would like to be hidden and filled
    registered_by = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.last_name, self.first_name)
```

and Views:

```
#views.py
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def guest_create(request):
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GuestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['first_name']= request.POST['first_name']
            request.session['last_name']= request.POST['last_name']
            request.session['e_mail']= request.POST['email']
            request.session['no_of_guests']= request.POST['no_of_guests']
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/guest_list_add/')
    else:
        form = GuestForm()
    return render_to_response('rsvp.html', locals(), context_instance,)

def guest_list_add(request):
    n = int(request.session['no_of_guests'])
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    GuestFormset = modelformset_factory(GuestsAttending, extra=int(n))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = GuestFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            instance = formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/submitted/')
    else:
        formset = GuestFormset(queryset=GuestsAttending.objects.none(), initial=[
            {'first_name': request.session['first_name'],
            'last_name': request.session['last_name'],
        ])
    return render_to_response('guest_list_add.html', locals(), context_instance,)
```

Let me know if you'd like to see any addition code- like templates maybe?

So, my question in a detailed summary-
How can I add request.session data (first & last name and email) to every "registered_by" field in my formset (view=guest_list_add, model=GuestsAttending)
Thanks!

Comment: See Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried filling your formset with that additional "referrer" data just before you save it on the database?

For instance, in the [saving objects in the formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) section of django's documentation on modelform formsets, you'll see that you can process the items on the formset if you do a `save(commit=False)` on the formset and then iterate on the instances inside the formset. That way, you can do pretty much whatever you want with them for example: you can fill them up with your referrer data.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using something similar to the code provided in the other answer below, but your answer is the same (and first) so I gave you the checkmark.

Answer (score 5):

Why does it need to be a hidden field in the formset? You've got access to that stuff in the view, why not just do it there?

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for form in formset:
        guest = form.save(commit=False)
        guest.invited_by = "%s %s" (request.session['first_name'], request.session['last_name'])
        guest.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was thinking in form mode and assumed that I needed to have some type of form input to process the db entries.

Comment: Got it working after a small caveat- the 4th line of this snippet needs to have a % between the 2 %s and (request....  So, "%s %s" % (request.session...  Thanks again

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem. :-)